# Character encoding for json2jsonp

Tags: json, character-encoding

I need some help with character encoding.
I want to access this api as a jsonp:

```
http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=<some phrase>&langpair=de|en
```

this works:

> http://json2jsonp.com/?url=http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Hund%26langpair=de|en&callback=cbfunc

but this doesn't:

> [http://json2jsonp.com/?url=http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Lösung%26langpair=de|en&callback=cbfunc](http://json2jsonp.com/?url=http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=L%C3%B6sung%26langpair=de|en&callback=cbfunc)

and `L%C3%B6sung` and `L%25C3%25B6sung` also don't work,
even though without json2jsonp, it works fine.

Any ideas / alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JSON2JSONP does not support non-ASCII characters.
`http://json2jsonp.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.mymemory.translated.net%2Fget%3Fq%3DL%25C3%25B6sung%26langpair%3Dde%257Cen&callback=cbfunc` should return the correct JSONP but actually an error occurs because JSON2JSONP sends an invalid HTTP GET request with `GET /get?q=L\xc3\xb6sung&langpair=de|en HTTP/1.1`, instead of `GET /get?q=L%C3%B6sung&langpair=de%7Cen HTTP/1.1`.

If you can use XMLHttpRequest and JSON.parse, you do not need JSONP anymore.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)  {
        cbfunc(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=L%C3%B6sung&langpair=de%7Cen");
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Cross-domain requests using this code works in Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 3+, Safari 4+ and IE 10+.